# Using xcopy to extract&copy files from certain subfolders

Tags: windows-10, command-line, xcopy, directory-listing

I have some data that is systematically organised into multiple-level subfolders, and I would like to copy all files that reside under certain subfolders, which I would like to specify using regexp-like syntax.

From the Windows 10 command prompt, I tried variations of the following command:

```
xcopy f:\Project\*\*Sess1\T1_*\*.* c:\CopyOfSelectedFiles\
```

Just to explain how I was using (perhaps incorrectly) the syntax of the command: the first * in the command indicates that I want to continue on to the next subfolder underneath, for all folders directly under the home Project folder. The *Sess1 indicates that I then want to only proceed deeper to those subfolders that end in "Sess1"; and so on...

I have tried both with `copy` and with `xcopy`, with various command flags/parameters such as `/s`, `/i`, etc; but each time I get error messages of this type:

```
File not found - *.*
0 File(s) copied
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you considered robocopy instead? it has much more robust options for selection and exclusion. https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Comment: I tried replacing xcopy with robocopy (as well as more playing around with the parameters), however I get similar errors. Maybe there's just something wrong in how I am using the parameters with which I am specifying the source files?

Comment: well, the arguments will be entirely different with powershell. can you show us what you glommed together?